# Get selected areas coordinate

Tags: swift, mkmapview

In my map the user can zoom in and zoom out, but how do I get the coordinates for the entire view that is visible for the user? I suspect that it might be the `regionDidChangeAnimated` but I have not been able to find appropiate parameters in that function.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the visible area by calling the instance method [visibleMapRect](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1452732-visiblemaprect) of `MKMapView`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.